# XSLT changing a node via a named template call from within a different node

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, scope, transformation

Edit: the error was in a wrong `when` condition.

Source xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mainNode>
   <levelOneNodes>
      <levelOneNode>
         <value name="triggeringValue">
            <levelTwoNodes>
               <levelTwoNode attributeOne="A" attributeTwo="A" attributeThree="A">
                  <textData>This is some text.</textData>
               </levelTwoNode>
               <levelTwoNode attributeOne="B1" attributeTwo="B1" attributeThree="B1">
                  <textData>This is some text.</textData>
               </levelTwoNode>
               <levelTwoNode attributeOne="C1" attributeTwo="C1" attributeThree="C1">
                  <textData>This is some text.</textData>
               </levelTwoNode>
            </levelTwoNodes>
         </value>
      </levelOneNode>
      <levelOneNode>
         <value name="anotherValue">
            <levelTwoNodes>
               <levelTwoNode attributeOne="A" attributeTwo="A" attributeThree="A">
                  <textData>This is some text.</textData>
               </levelTwoNode>
               <levelTwoNode attributeOne="B2" attributeTwo="B2" attributeThree="B2">
                  <textData>This is some text.</textData>
               </levelTwoNode>
               <levelTwoNode attributeOne="C2" attributeTwo="C2" attributeThree="C2">
                  <textData>This is some text.</textData>
               </levelTwoNode>
            </levelTwoNodes>
         </value>
      </levelOneNode>
    </levelOneNodes>
</mainNode>
```

Expected trasnformed xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mainNode>
   <levelOneNodes>
      <levelOneNode>
         <value name="triggeringValue">
            <levelTwoNodes>
               <levelTwoNode injectedAttribute="triggeringValue" attributeOne="A" attributeTwo="A" attributeThree="A">
                  <textData>This is some text.</textData>
               </levelTwoNode>
               <levelTwoNode injectedAttribute="triggeringValue" attributeOne="B1" attributeTwo="B1" attributeThree="B1">
                  <textData>This is some text.</textData>
               </levelTwoNode>
               <levelTwoNode injectedAttribute="triggeringValue" attributeOne="C1" attributeTwo="C1" attributeThree="C1">
                  <textData>This is some text.</textData>
               </levelTwoNode>
            </levelTwoNodes>
         </value>
      </levelOneNode>
      <levelOneNode>
         <value name="anotherValue">
            <levelTwoNodes>
               <levelTwoNode injectedAttribute="triggeringValue" attributeOne="A" attributeTwo="A" attributeThree="A">
                  <textData>This is some text.</textData>
               </levelTwoNode>
               <levelTwoNode attributeOne="B2" attributeTwo="B2" attributeThree="B2">
                  <textData>This is some text.</textData>
               </levelTwoNode>
               <levelTwoNode attributeOne="C2" attributeTwo="C2" attributeThree="C2">
                  <textData>This is some text.</textData>
               </levelTwoNode>
            </levelTwoNodes>
         </value>
      </levelOneNode>
    </levelOneNodes>
</mainNode>
```

That is, when a *levelTwoNode* node nested into a *value* node with attribute *name* "*triggeringValue*" is encountered, all the *levelTwoNode* nodes in the document with the same *attributeOne* and *attributeTwo* as the triggering node's should be injected with the attribute *injectedAttribute="triggeringValue"*.

I am using this xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>                        
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

    <xsl:output encoding="Windows-1252" method="xml" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="no" />

    <!-- Copy the whole output -->
    <xsl:template match="@* |node() ">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* |node() "/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//levelOneNodes/levelOneNode/value/levelTwoNodes/levelTwoNode" >
    
        <xsl:call-template name="myTemplate">
        
            <xsl:with-param name="myAttrOne" select=" current()/@attributeOne " />
            <xsl:with-param name="myAttrTwo" select=" current()/@attributeTwo " />
            <xsl:with-param name="myValue" select=" current()/../../@name " />

        </xsl:call-template>

    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template name="myTemplate">    

        <xsl:param name="myAttrOne" />
        <xsl:param name="myAttrTwo" />
        <xsl:param name="myValue" />

        <xsl:choose>

            <xsl:when test="boolean(//levelTwoNode[(@attributeOne = $myAttrOne) and (@attributeTwo = $myAttrTwo)]) and boolean($myValue = 'triggeringValue')">
            
                <xsl:copy>
                
                    <xsl:attribute name="injectedAttribute"><xsl:value-of select="$myValue"/></xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* |node() "/>

                </xsl:copy>

            </xsl:when>

            <xsl:otherwise>
            
                <xsl:copy>
                
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* |node() "/>

                </xsl:copy>

            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>

    </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

that results in this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?><mainNode>
   <levelOneNodes>
      <levelOneNode>
         <value name="triggeringValue">
            <levelTwoNodes>
               <levelTwoNode injectedAttribute="triggeringValue" attributeOne="A" attributeTwo="A" attributeThree="A">
                  <textData>This is some text.</textData>
               </levelTwoNode>
               <levelTwoNode injectedAttribute="triggeringValue" attributeOne="B1" attributeTwo="B1" attributeThree="B1">
                  <textData>This is some text.</textData>
               </levelTwoNode>
               <levelTwoNode injectedAttribute="triggeringValue" attributeOne="C1" attributeTwo="C1" attributeThree="C1">
                  <textData>This is some text.</textData>
               </levelTwoNode>
            </levelTwoNodes>
         </value>
      </levelOneNode>
      <levelOneNode>
         <value name="anotherValue">
            <levelTwoNodes>
               <levelTwoNode attributeOne="A" attributeTwo="A" attributeThree="A">
                  <textData>This is some text.</textData>
               </levelTwoNode>
               <levelTwoNode attributeOne="B2" attributeTwo="B2" attributeThree="B2">
                  <textData>This is some text.</textData>
               </levelTwoNode>
               <levelTwoNode attributeOne="C2" attributeTwo="C2" attributeThree="C2">
                  <textData>This is some text.</textData>
               </levelTwoNode>
            </levelTwoNodes>
         </value>
      </levelOneNode>
    </levelOneNodes>
</mainNode>
```

where the new attribute *injectedAttribute* is not injected into the first *levelTwoNode* of the second *levelOneNode* (the one with the child node *value* with attribute *name* "*anotherValue*") even though it has the same *attributeOne* and *attributeTwo* (with value "*A*") of one of the *levelTwoNode* nodes inside the first *levelOneNode* node (the one with the child node *value* with attribute *name* "*triggeringValue*"). The attribute *injectedAttribute* is injected only in all the *levelTwoNode* nodes inside the *triggeringValue* *value* node.

Why does this condition:

```
<xsl:when test="boolean(//levelTwoNode[(@attributeOne = $myAttrOne) and (@attributeTwo = $myAttrTwo)]) and boolean($myValue = 'triggeringValue')">
```

is limited in the scope of the calling node? The query `//levelTwoNode[(@attributeOne = $myAttrOne) and (@attributeTwo = $myAttrTwo)]` should fetch all levelTwoNode nodes with the passed attributes and the condition `$myValue = 'triggeringValue'` should not limit that query.

What am I missing?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say "the condition $myValue = 'triggeringValue' should not limit that query" but it should. The variable $myValue is bound to `current()/../../@name` and I think you will find its value is "anotherValue".

Comment: Thanks! I was indeed wrong on that one! I set the condition to ```when test="boolean(//levelOneNode/value[@name='triggeringValue']/levelTwoNodes/levelTwoNode[(@attributeOne = $myAttrOne) and (@attributeTwo = $myAttrTwo)])"``` which now does what I was expecting.

Answer (score 1):

This is very confusing. I could not understand your code at all. If I understand your description correctly (which is a VERY big if), then you want to do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="trigger" match="value[@name='triggeringValue']/levelTwoNodes/levelTwoNode" use="concat(@attributeOne, '|', @attributeTwo)" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="levelTwoNode[key('trigger', concat(@attributeOne, '|', @attributeTwo))]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="injectedAttribute">triggeringValue</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The way this works is it indexes all `levelTwoNode` elements that are descendants of `<value name="triggeringValue">`. Then, any `levelTwoNode` element that has the same two attribute values as one of the indexed elements (incl. the indexed elements themselves) is modified by adding the `injectedAttribute` attribute.

Comment: Hi Michael! First of all thanks for your help and for your attention, really. The results you posted indeed are as expected. My concern is also about understanding why the call-template instruction results in a different xml. Your pointing out that the code didn't make sense helped me in taking a step back and seeing the absurdity I ended up with (nothing like a fresh morning to see one's mess!).

Comment: The *when* condition was nonsense. Instead, I should have checked for:
```when test="boolean(//levelOneNode/value[@name='triggeringValue']/levelTwoNodes/levelTwoNode[(@attributeOne = $myAttrOne) and (@attributeTwo = $myAttrTwo)])"```
This results in the expected xml.
That is, I was binding the *'triggeringValue'* to the node from which the *call-template* was applied, instead of simply checking for the presence of any *levelTwoNode* (with the same attributes of the node the *call-template* is applied to) which is inside a *levelOneNode* with attribute *name* set to *'triggeringValue'*.